# jquery content slider similar to microsoft.com

Tags: jquery, scroll, slider

Looking to implement a jquery content slider similar to the TOP PRODUCTS section on microsoft.com.  Just wondering if someone can push me in the right direction here.  I guess the whole parent and children relationship is where I'm struggling to wrap my head around.

Answer (score 0):

CeeMonet,
    See this : http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/28-useful-jquery-sliders-you-need-to-download/

ans also

http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/

Lots too choose from.
Cheers

Comment: I have no problem implementing a regular jquery content slider.  My issue is that I'm looking to have groups or headers, and then scroll through the children when clicking on the header. that's the piece that I'm not sure about.

Comment: So if thats the case you would have to generate the HTML you need.
Check out : http://www.kyrielles.net/sliderkit/sliderkit_en.html
and look for newslider.
Cheers